# segmentation fault scanf'ing pointer to string

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I'm developing a program that stores variables of type client in a linked list. However im getting a segmentation fault on the scanfs. Pointers are new to me, so I assume there's something wrong with the `name` variable. Service is defined by one letter.

```
typedef struct{
    char* name;
    unsigned long number;
    char service;
}Client; 

struct node {
    Cliente value;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node *LinkedListNode;



int main(){
    LinkedListNode head;
    Cliente aux,aux2;
    char command;
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->next=NULL;
    comando= getchar();
    while(1){ 
    switch(command){
        case('a'):
                scanf("%s",aux.name);
                scanf("%lu",&aux.number);
                scanf("%c",&aux.service);
                if(list_search_name(head,aux)==0){                      
                    if(list_search_number(head,aux)==0)                 
                        list_insert(head,aux);
                }   
                getchar();
        break;
```

The if chain in the command simply checks if the inserted name and number already exist in the list, in order to insert.

One other question I have is this: From what i've been told you're supposed to have one `free()` for each `malloc()` or else some memory will leak, but in this case the `head` variable is needed throughout the entire program because I use it in every command to store/search/get data. Should I still free the memory when the program closes anyway?

Comment: The reason for the one free() per malloc() rule of thumb is to prevent a memory leak (see this [wikipedia memory leaks article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) as well as this article on [pointers and memory leaks in C](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-toughgame/) ).  With modern run time libraries on most operating systems, when a program terminates all allocated memory is returned back to the operating system.  However matching free() to malloc() is a good habit to cultivate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using undefined string pointers, leading to undefined behavior.

Change the declaration to:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[32];
    unsigned long number;
    char service;
}Client;
```

and the first `scanf()` to:

```
scanf("%31s", aux.name);
```

Also, you should check the return value of `scanf()`, it's I/O so it can fail.